# Converting CoordinateMatrix to RowMatrix doesn't preserve row order

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

In Spark-shell, I created a CoordinateMatrix:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.{
  CoordinateMatrix, MatrixEntry}
val entries = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  Array(0, 1, 1), Array(0, 2, 2), Array(0, 3, 3), 
  Array(0, 4, 4), Array(1, 2, 5), Array(1, 3, 6),
  Array(1, 4, 7), Array(2, 3, 8), Array(2, 4, 9),
  Array(3, 4, 10))).map(f => MatrixEntry(f(0), f(1), f(2)))

val mat: CoordinateMatrix = new CoordinateMatrix(entries)
```

which is:

```
0 1 2 3 4
0 0 5 6 7
0 0 0 8 9
0 0 0 0 10
```

Now I want to convert it to RowMatrix and see the entries:

```
scala> mat.toRowMatrix.rows.collect
res1: Array[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector] = Array((5,[1,2,3,4],[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0]), (5,[2,3,4],[5.0,6.0,7.0]), (5,[4],[10.0]), (5,[3,4],[8.0,9.0]))
```

It is strange that the third and forth row are exchanged in RowMatrix. What's the problem with that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not strange. As you can read in [the API docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix), `RowMatrix`:

> Represents a row-oriented distributed Matrix with **no meaningful row indices**.

Moreover converting `CoordinateMatrix` to any other type of distributed matrix requires repartitioning and the order of the output rows / blocks depends partially on the number of partitions and dimensions of the matrix but beyond that it is not deterministic.

If order of rows is important you should use [`IndexedRowMatrix`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-data-types.html#indexedrowmatrix). It still doesn't guarantee the order of the rows but `IndexedRow` preserves indices which can be used to reorder rows if necessary.

Comment: My pleasure. I've realized that the original answer wasn't exactly clear so I've added some clarifications.